# class A amplifier of 10W for 8ohm load

Tags: amplifier

I Want to know how to design good class A amplifier of 10W for 8ohm load. with common emitter stage for input and emitter follower for output.with minimum component [image: Class A]quantity.first stage is below Vc is about 12.34V and Ic is 6mA maximum 10 mA. I have 25 v 4A supply please help with detail.

Comment: Build this amp: http://www.firstwatt.com/pdf/art_zen_amp.pdf

Comment: We don't do "hey you, design this for me!" type of questions, especially not when they smell of homework. How far did you get with your design? Do you have any *specific* questions about it?

Comment: this is not homework and i am not a student i am just interested in audio electronics . professionally i am stock trader ok. can you interested to help now. I am trying but not working well. only get 1.5W watt on 8ohm load.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this site does not respond to "Hey design this for me" type questions.